# Roblox Studio how to loop check if a players name is correctly typed into a texbox

Tags: roblox

I'm making my admin panel. I have a problem when I write this:

```
if script.Parent.Frame.PlayersTrollFrame.Textbox == game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name then
    print("yes")
else
    print("no")
```

How can I get this to loop check the name without a game script timeout

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the textbox's contents in a loop, you should use the [:GetPropertyChangedSignal(propertyName)](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetPropertyChangedSignal) functions to get the event that fires whenever a certain property is changed. In this case, we want to get the event that fires whenever the Text property changes:

```lua
script.Parent.Frame.PlayersTrollFrame.TextBox:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Text"):Connect(function()
    if script.Parent.Frame.PlayersTrollFrame.Textbox == game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name then
        print("yes")
    else
        print("no")
    end
end)
```

[:Connect(function)](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/events#connecting-a-function) makes it so that whenever the event is fired, it runs the function that's passed through.

However, if you **really** need to use a loop for some reason, you can do so by putting the if statement in a **while wait() do** loop

```lua
while wait() do
    if script.Parent.Frame.PlayersTrollFrame.Textbox.Text == game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name then
        print("yes")
    else
        print("no")
    end
end
```